# For TimeComplexity analysis ima need help with a Summation

Tags: algorithm, sum, time-complexity

for an algorithm time complexity analysis i need to know what is the result of the summation of the function n/i when i runs from 1 to logn, i saw somewhere trustable that is actually the harmonic sum, but i highly doubt it...

the function of the algorithm was originally T(n)=5T(n/5)+n/logn

this question was originally found at the Introduction to algorithms second edition book

save me! :)

http://faculties.sbu.ac.ir/~tahmasbi/DataStructure/Introduction%20to%20Algorithms-Cormen%20Solution.pdf

in page 58,there's a line say:

=n*sigma n/i where i goes from 1 to logn

=n*sigma 1/i where i goes from 1 to logn

thats the only part i have problem with.... cause all they did was taking that n out of the sigma, but where is it gone to? why is it true to just make it disappear?

as opposed to what they're saying i think it should be like:

=n*sigma n/i where i goes from 1 to logn

=n*n*sigma 1/i where i goes from 1 to logn

=n^2*sigma 1/i where i goes from 1 to logn

Comment: the answer is `math error`, for `n/0`, the first element. do you mean from 1 to logn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is indeed harmonic sum:

`n/1 + n/2 + ... + n/logn = n* [ 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/logn] = n*H(logn)` where `H(logn)` is the logn [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

the book uses `H(m) = theta(logm)` and because of this, `H(logn) = theta(loglogn)`. so at overall we get: `T(n) = n*H(logn) = n*theta(loglogn) = theta(n*loglogn)`.

Comment: I agree with you, but then u get O(nlogn) not O(logn) like you would get for just the harmonic figure

Comment: @Ofek Ron: see my edit, the book `uses H(m) = theta(logm)`, and it uses it to say `T(n) = n*H(logn) = n * theta(loglogn) = theta(n*loglogn)`

Comment: one of us doesnt understand the other, edited the question trying to be more specific of what i dont get

Comment: @Ofek Ron: It seems just a typing error to me, the surplus 'n' arrived from nowhere and vanish back. I study at the technion [Haifa], CS faculty, starting 4th year soon.